# Can I create multiple account with same ip in google play console?

Tags: android

I want another developer account for my apps. Can I create another account on same pc (IP) where my other developer account stand for uploading apps?

Comment: you can create multiple, there is a cost to it. Amazon android store is free though

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can, it will cost an extra $25. Just take care not to do any illegal or IP infringement stuffs like copyright music. Or you could get both account banned based on IP association. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll have to pay the $25 developer fee again. Account are not device or IP exclusive. You can log in and use your account on other devices and networks. Outside of publishing under a different name, company, or to keep apps separate for whatever business purposes, I don't really see what you would want that second account though.